# Which permissions do I have to set

Tags: windows, windows-8, permissions

I want to create a folder F. Everybody from User group could create a folders and files inside this folder F. But if somebody (user X from User group) created a folder N inside folder F, another users from User group couldn't create folders and files inside this new folder N.

Do you have any ideas how to set those permissions and how?

EDIT: I've created a desired folder F. To set permissions I've clicked on folder properties -> security -> advanced. I couldn't change anything when Users group was selected, so I've disabled `inheritance`. Now, I can change all permissions. But I can't find a combination to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

Best practice is to create dedicated folders for each usergroup and give other usergroups read permissions.

So:

```
Data\F would have group F = full control, H = Read, N = Read
Data\H would have group H = full control, F = Read, N = Read
Data\N would have group N = full control, F = Read, H = Read
```

If a user from F creates a new folder in F: eg `Data\F\food` and posts files in it, users from H and N can read it, but not make changes.
If a user from H does the same in H: eg `Data\H\health` the same applies.

It is not possible to restrict it so that a user can change files, but not create folders.

Design your file structure around this.